# Catch exception in iteration of ContextMenuStrip items

Tags: vb.net, iterator, contextmenustrip

I'm trying to iterate over contextmenustrip items like this:

```
Public Sub TranslateContextMenuStrip(ByRef u As ContextMenuStrip)

    For Each t As ToolStripMenuItem In u.Items 'here the error occurs
        pProcessMenuItem(t) 'not here
    Next

End Sub
```

But I have toolstrip separators in the contextmenustrip, and I'm getting the error

"System.InvalidCastException: The object of type System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator can't be converted to type System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem"

as soon as it stumbles over a separator.

I wonder why this separator is included in items (I am requesting "For Each t As ToolStripMenuItem" so why does it return non-ToolStripMenuItems???) and how to catch this error or avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `For Each t As ToolStripMenuItem` does what you might think it does.

It simply declares that the `t` iterator will be of Type `ToolStripMenuItem`.  It does nothing to the item collection itself.  When you come to seperator, you get the cast exception because a separator cannot be converted to a menu item.

`Items` is a collection of `ToolStripItem`s.  This is a base class used for all the Types a context menu can hold (menu item, combo, text box or separator).  Since these all inherit from `ToolStripItem` the collection can hold any of them (specifically, a `ToolStripSeparator` item is also a `ToolStripItem`)

There are several ways to iterate or work with just the menu entries:

#### Filter the Items collection

```
For Each tsi As ToolStripMenuItem In u.Items.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem)()
    ' do something fun with tsi
Next
```

The `OfType()` extension filters the items collection to just menu items.

This is by far the simplest because your iterator `tsi` is the proper type.  This is particularly true if your method is writen to expect menu items:

```
Sub pProcessMenuItem(item As ToolStripMenuItem)
```

The `tsi` iterator is same Type expected by the method, so no further steps are needed.  Anything else will require casting either in the method or to call the method (or Option Strict Off).

#### Test the Type:

```
' iterate all the items 
For Each tsi As ToolStripItem In u.Items
    ' test the type of each 
    If TypeOf tsi Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
        ' do something fun with tsi
    End If
Next
```

Under `Option Strict` passing `tsi` to a method declared as shown above wont compile.  You would have to cast before invoking your method:

```
pProcessMenuItem(CType(tsi, ToolStripMenuItem))
```

If the method is declared to accept a `ToolStripItem` or `Object`, the cast would have to take place in the method if you need to access any menu related properties.

---

The same is true using `As Object` to iterate:

```
For Each it As Object In u.Items
    If TypeOf it Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
        pProcessMenuItem(it)
    End If
Next
```

The only way this will compile under `Option Strict` if the method argument is declared `As Object`.  As above, `Object` may have to be cast to `ToolStripMenuItem`.  The first method prevents any need for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but not the problem:

```
    For Each it As Object In u.Items
        If TypeOf it Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
            pProcessMenuItem(it)
        End If
    Next
```